# HTML Website Log Out

Tags: javascript, html, logging, out

I'm a newbie in HTML, but I'm trying to build a small web application. The user logs on, and there's a *log out* link. When the user clicks the `log-out` button, the the main log-in pages displays. But when the user clicks the back-button in the browser, he's again in the app. How can I disable that?

I've tested this with Hotmail.com. You login to your email account. Then choose log out and you get to the MSN website. When you then push the back-button you get again the log-in page and not the page with your inbox.

How can this be achieved with html and/or Javascript?

Comment: assuming you're using a LAMP server, you need to create a session (PHP session variable) when the user logs in and display the appropriate content only if the session variables are correctly set.  Clicking the logout button (or link) destroys the session and redirects the user.

Comment: Not possible with `html and/or Javascript`. You need php.

Comment: you can't check it  only in javascript and html. something server side mechanism needed to check whether login session exist or not to determine whether redirect to login page on pressing back button.

other way to handle just using client side by using web api like indexedDb or local storage or cookie to determine whether on press of back button where to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I see that it isn't possible in just html and javascript. I'm not using PHP but Webspeed (Progress OpenEdge), but it works the same way. At my serversite I have a database where the session are stored in and when the user log-outs, I set the session in the database not valid. But when the user presses the back-button in the browser, the page isn't actualy loaded but just displayed. I see that you mention cookies. So when the user logs out I could set a cookie. But how can I check that cookie when the user presses the back-button ? How can I capture that event ?

Answer (score 0):

Your pages are being cached. You can either use javascript to force redirect the browser or turn off caching for your protected pages using meta tags/modifying the http response in your code behind.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: What I do, when a page gets loaded there some server-side scripting involved that checks if the session is valid, if not it just shows up the login screen and alerting that the session is expired.  But that just my problem, if they press back-button in the browser the page isn't loaded but just shown. It's the back-button of the browser, not a back-link that I place on my html-files.

Comment: Hi, Tried it with the meta-tags you mentioned, and no luck. If I press the back button, the previous page is just shown and the server-side code isn't executed....

Comment: Did you try to set it directly in the response headers? Meta tags are a poor substitute. I added them only because I have no experience with the stack you are using. To help further I would need more information about the  server technologies used.

Comment: The server side technologie is Webspeed (Progress OpenEdge). So I think that not many people can help me out with this ...